# Render multiple templates at once in Flask

Tags: templates, render, flask

I'm making a Flask application. I have a login area, a blogs area. If I want to get user's login, I'll render login template. But this doesn't render the blog template that has to be displayed below the login area. :/

I'll try to make it clearer:

```
{% block login %} {% endblock %}
blah blah
{% block blog_display %} {% endblock %}
```

Now i have a `login.html` which extends this, and goes into login block. I have a `blogs.html` which goes into `blog_display`. How to I render both? When I do `render_template()`, i can call it on only one of the `login.html` or `blogs.html`.

Please help me out. I'll give more details if you ask for it.

Comment: Better yet, if there are two blocks in your master template, and you want to get them from two different child templates, what do you do? And how do you solve the crisis if there is no way to do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You may be thinking about layouts the wrong way.  Your layout is the *most* generic of your templates, not your most complex one. If you need little self-contained pieces of functionality then write them up *just as they are* and [`include`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include) them where they are needed.

That is to say, if you want something like this:

```
----------------------------------
                  +--------------+
  Header          |   Login      |
                  +--------------+
----------------------------------

  Body Content (Blog)
```

And you also want to have a stand-alone login page like this:

```
----------------------------------

  Header

----------------------------------

  +--------------+
  |   Login      |
  +--------------+
```

Then create a login partial and [`include`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include) it where you need it.

### Example

**templates/partials/login.html**

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
<!-- Your login goes here -->
</form>
```

**templates/your_base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
{% block head %}
{# 
Default HEAD content goes here 
with extra nested blocks for children to override 
if needed. 
#}
{% endblock head %}
</head>
<body>
<header>{% block header %}{% endblock header %}</header>
{# Note: This assumes we *always* want a header #}
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

**templates/login.html**

```
{% extends "your_base.html" -%}
{% block content -%}
{% include "partials/login.html" %}
{%- endblock content %}
```

**templates/blog.html**

```
{% extends "your_base.html" -%}
{% block header -%}
{{ super() }}{# Render the default header contents here #}
{% include "partials/login.html" %}
{%- endblock header %}
{% block content -%}
{# Render your blog posts here #}
{%- endblock content %}
```

Comment: You first say "block head" then "block header". Is that a typo?

Comment: `your_base` has both a `head` and a `header` section - we only override `header` in `blog` but I wanted to show that you could have sections you *don't* override as well as ones you did.

Answer (score 10):

Sean's answer works good, but if you don't want to extend blocks you can pick up a simpler solution, which i prefer more.

```
{% include "partials/login.html" %}
```

Just use it anywhere you need to include the template

Comment: What if we want to pass some parameters to this template, like a variable indicating whether the user is logged in to adjust the view accordingly.