# Return multiple templates

Tags: javascript, flask

I am currently trying open multiple pages on a POST request. Basically, what I am doing is searching for a job number in the database by sending a POST request and then (trying) opening the multiple pages that correspond with that job number (ex.: a webpage for job location, one for material, etc.) However, I can only return one template for the browser to open. I have looked at many, many questions like this one:

[Render multiple templates at once in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946795/render-multiple-templates-at-once-in-flask)

However, I am not finding the answer to my question (most likely because I am asking the wrong question...)
Anyway, my code so far is something like this:

HTML:

```
<form action="/testing" method="POST" id="existBidFormOne" name="existBidFormOne" autocomplete="off">
        <!-- Row one holds Title-->
        <div class="center row" style="width: 100%;">
            <h1>Enter a Job Number or a Project Name:</h1>
        </div>

        <!-- Row two holds job number-->
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Column one holds Job number-->
            <div class="col-m-6">
                <div class="row centerInput">
                    <div class="col-m-4 inputPad"><b>Job Number:</b></div>
                    <div class="col-m-8 noPad">
                        <input type="text" id="exb_jobNumber" name="exb_jobNumber" class="input maxWidth" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="centerInput row">
            <span>
                <button type="submit" id="exb_searchOne" class="srchBtn">Search</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
```

FLASK:

```
@app.route('/testing', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def testing():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        job_num = request.form.getlist('exb_jobNumber')
        if job_num:
            session = Session()
            results = ds.get_job_info(session, job_num) # returns dict
            results2 = ds.get_job_material(session, job_num) #returns dict
            session.close()
            # open page one
            return render_template('pageOne.html', **results)
```

The above code works well opening one page, however I would also like to open:

```
render_template('pageTwo.html', **results2)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*opening the multiple pages* If you want to open multiple pages on a single webpage (i.e. in a single browser tab), then you can combine and render as many separate templates as you want with [template inheritance](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#template-inheritance). You can have single base page and nest many sub-pages with any content you want.

If you want to open multiple pages in multiple browser tabs, then you should return only a single main HTML page (i.e. single template), but set variable in that webpage with links of all pages you want to open in new browser tabs. Then, with the help of [JavaScript and browser API method window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) you can open those pages.